# `android` Does Not Exist in `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

Tags: android, android-studio, configuration, sdk

I recently downloaded and installed Android Studio on my system (Ubuntu 22). I added the paths `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` to `~/.bashrc` and now the `adb` command works properly. However, I keep getting the error message `bash: android: command not found`. In fact `android` does not exist in those directories.

I appreciate any insights into why this might be happening and how to resolve.